# FactoryBot ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error with wrong class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Good morning,

I am working on a proof of concept Rails application after a long break from using Rails. I set up RSpec tests, as well as FactoryBot and Faker to generate test data. In my app, I have two models:

```rb
class Admin::Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :description

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users,
                          association_foreign_key: :admin_user_id,
                          foreign_key: :admin_tenant_id

  has_many :tenant_groups,
           inverse_of: :tenant,
           dependent: :destroy,
           class_name: 'Tenant::Group'

  validates :name,
            presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 255 }
end

class Tenant::Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :description

  belongs_to :tenant,
             class_name: 'Admin::Tenant',
             inverse_of: :tenant_groups

  validates :name,
            presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 255 }

  acts_as_tenant :tenant
end
```

I also have the two factories defined:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :admin_tenant, class: 'Admin::Tenant' do
    name { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  end

  factory :tenant_group, class: 'Tenant::Group' do
    association :tenant, factory: :admin_tenant
    name { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  end
end
```

When utilizing the factory `:admin_tenant` on its own, it seems to work fine, but when I attempt to generate a `:tenant_group` (using `create(:tenant_group)`) I receive an error in rspec:

```
     Failure/Error: let(:tenant_group) { create(:tenant_group) }

     ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Tenant(#52813860) expected, got #<Admin::Tenant id: 295, name: "Perspiciatis sit numquam fugit.", created_at: "2020-01-03 15:08:13", updated_at: "2020-01-03 15:08:13"> which is an instance of Admin::Tenant(#55283820)
```

It seems that for some reason, it is assuming the class of the factory should be something else. Since I specify `class_name` in the association, I'd assume it would work (it does when I'm using the application itself). I saw that Spring might cause issues, so I followed the advice of the FactoryBot README and placed `config.before(:suite) { FactoryBot.reload }` in my rails_helper.rb file.

#### Update 1

Now finding out that the problem lies with `acts_as_tenant`. The stack trace was too short in RSpec output to realize what the issue was, but now it's showing up in regular usage, as well.

#### Update 2

I'm going to go ahead and mark this as solved. It doesn't appear to be an issue with FactoryBot as I initially thought, but rather an issue with my understanding of `acts_as_tenant`. When the class name cannot be easily inferred by the association name, you must specify the `:class_name` option. This became clear after browsing the source code for a bit. In retrospect, it seems obvious, since all associations seem to behave the same way...

Comment: I don't think this is a FactoryBot issue at all. FactoryBot is actually doing exactly what its supposed to and creating an instance of `Admin::Tenant`. The issue is the association itself in the model. I haven't used ActsAsTenant but my guess is that `acts_as_tenant :tenant` actually defines an association that overwrites `belongs_to :tenant, class_name: 'Admin::Tenant' ...` with an assocation without the class name option. You can investigate this by calling `Tenant::Group.reflect_on_association(:tenant)`.

Comment: I think your code looks good... had a quick google and these workarounds might help: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#rails-preloaders-and-rspec

Comment: Try adding to your rspec config:

Comment: `RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) { FactoryBot.reload }
end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is most likely caused by `ActsAsTenant` and not `FactoryBot` which is doing the right thing.

When you create multiple associations with the same name the later overwrite the former. And `acts_as_tenant :tenant` does just that and clobbers the association you already set up. Its not very well documented but [the `acts_as_tenant` macro](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant/blob/1ba28d1354848fd422603efa343b145bae5c5fdf/lib/acts_as_tenant/model_extensions.rb#L103) takes roughly the same options as `belongs_to`.

```
class Tenant::Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :description
  acts_as_tenant :tenant,
    class_name: 'Admin::Tenant',
    inverse_of: :tenant_groups

  validates :name,
            presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to reflect this about the same time you answered. Looks like we came to the same conclusion. Thanks for the help!